# LINQ - select from two arrays

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query syntax expression, and i am failing to convert it to a extension methods syntax expression.

This is the original expression :

```
List<int> arr1 = new List<int>();
List<int> arr2 = new List<int>();

var nerArr = from a1 in arr1
                from a2 in arr2
                let sum = a1 + a2
                where sum > 10
                where sum < 20
                select new { a1, a2, sum };
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to convert it to method syntax?  Or are you just curious?

Comment: You can use: `var nerArr2 = arr1.SelectMany(a1 => arr2, (a1, a2) => new {a1 = a1, a2 = a2, sum = a1 + a2}).Where(a => a.sum > 10 && a.sum < 20).Select(a => new {a.a1, a.a2, a.sum});`

Comment: for practicing. your query works. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's, as always, much simpler with Method syntax - albeit cross joins are a bit weird looking

```
var nerArr2 = arr1.Join(arr2, x => true, y => true, (a1,a2) => new {a1,a2,sum=a1+a2})
                 .Where(x => x.sum > 10 && x.sum <20);
```

Live example (showing original and this implementation): http://rextester.com/MSY85791

You can also do this with a `SelectMany` as noted elsewhere.

Comment: I disagree that it's "simpler".  Query syntax is _much_ cleaner for joins.

Comment: For joins, yes - for everything else no. And if I wrote a very quick extension method called `CrossJoin` this would look much simpler - `arr1.CrossJoin(arr2, (x,y) => new {...})`

Comment: whats the purpose of testing `(x) => true, y => true` ? Are you filtering out null ?

Comment: @cableload The 2nd and 3rd parameter of the `Join` method select the keys to compare for the LHS & RHS of the join. for a cross join these just need to match for all records. I could have returned `1` for both, or `"foo"` - it doesnt matter as long as they match.

Comment: Yes, got it thanks! Just reading about the join extension method.